# Converting table columns to spatial objects

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, r-sf

I'm looking for the best and workable solution when it comes to converting raw data from db to sf object.
I need to create POINTs of raw coordinates (of type float). I found one solution to do this where we create sf object from raw data like this:

```
lnd_point = st_point(c(0.1, 51.5)) 
lnd_geom = st_sfc(lnd_point, crs = 4326)
lnd_attrib = data.frame(
  name = 'London',
  temperature = 25,
  date = as.Date('2017-06-21')
)
lnd_sf = st_sf(lnd_attrib, geometry = lnd_geom)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't apply to table columns. Here is my database table (named 'tableDB'):

[image]

Like in the example above, first I wanted to create 2 separate geom columns of POINT type (for lonCust/latCust and lonApp/latApp using st_point), then create list of points (using st_sfc) and finally create sf object (using st_sf) but it doesn't work in my case.

Generally speaking, I need to create POINT data type of lonCust/latCust and lonApp/latApp in 2 separate columns (2 geometry columns placed at the end of the data frame). First I want to convert them to POINTs but `st_point` doesn't work for columns, as I mentioned before. What I found in the book and on the internet is this:

```
newDF <- tableDB %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lonCust","latCust"), crs = 4326)
```

After that, my 'newDF' became 'sf' and 'data.frame' object what is ok but I still need to make 2 geom columns, not one. Don't know how to add second and more geom columns at the end of df. Summing up, I have a few questions:

1. What's the best way to convert raw data from db into spatial objects (e.g. POINTs)?
2. How to add more geom columns to a data frame (like in my example, I need to have 2 geom POINT columns: for ..Cust and ..App)?
3. Is it good practice to subtract e.g. lat/lon columns from original df and create a new, separate sf object? If so then how can I pair/assign each spatial point with an attribute (like with ZLP or LP in my example above)?

I'm really interested in good practices in terms of converting raw data into spatial data - I want to write Shiny app and need to know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `sf` object can have two geometry columns, but only one will be 'active'.  Example and explanation here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf6.html

Starting from the dataframe that you posted in the image & naming it `my_df`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

my_sf <- my_df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c('lonCust', 'latCust')) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)

my_sf$geom2 <- my_df %>% st_as_sf(coords = c('lonApp', 'latApp')) %>%
  st_geometry()
```

Should work.  An example with made up data below:

```
x <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                lon = sample(1:10, size = 10, replace = T),
                lat = sample(1:10, size = 10, replace = T),
                lon2 = sample(1:10, size = 10, replace = T),
                lat2 = sample(1:10, size = 10, replace = T))

xsf <- st_as_sf(x, coords = c('lon', 'lat'), remove = F)

xsf$geometry2 <- st_as_sf(x, coords = c('lon2', 'lat2')) %>%
  st_geometry()

head(xsf)
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 5 fields
#> Active geometry column: geometry
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 8 ymax: 7
#> CRS:            NA
#>   id lon lat lon2 lat2    geometry    geometry2
#> 1  1   8   1    4    4 POINT (8 1)  POINT (4 4)
#> 2  2   8   6   10    8 POINT (8 6) POINT (10 8)
#> 3  3   7   7    2    6 POINT (7 7)  POINT (2 6)
#> 4  4   1   1    7    2 POINT (1 1)  POINT (7 2)
#> 5  5   5   3    3    9 POINT (5 3)  POINT (3 9)
#> 6  6   6   2    3    8 POINT (6 2)  POINT (3 8)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm wondering if it's good approach to have a few geom columns in one data frame? If no, what is the reason for not having them there? (I asked this question in my post in point 3)

Comment: Generally I've seen one geometry column & separate data frames, or a single df with one geom col & a column to filter on. Most functions in `sf` seem to have been made to work best with a single geom column. I've never come across a case where more than 2 geometry columns are used. Depending on your use case, you may want to have two dataframes. One with a Cust geometry & one with App geometry. They can be joined & filtered using zlp & lp if those columns are unique enough.

Comment: That makes sense:) So let's say I want to add one more geometry column (e.g. LINESTRING) - the best option then would be creating another df with this geometry column and join with other dataframes if needed?

Comment: That would probably be my approach, but it depends on what your goal is. Maybe figure out what you're trying to end up with & ask another here on SO. sf has functions to connect the points (and return a linestring) if that's what you're headed towards.